# Algolia: Filter on attribute with type boolean

Tags: algolia

In Algolia, I have the following object in index "users":

```
{
    "name": "Jaap",
    "objectID": 1,
    "isActivated": true
}
```

I want to get all objects from index "users" where "isActivated" is true. How should the filter string look? I already tried "isActivated", "isActivated:true", "isActivated=true"... it all doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Alright, I was impatient:

```
"isActivated=1"
```

This worked for me. Booleans are treated as numbers; true = 1 and false = 0.